# Update time realtime in PHP / Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Is it possible to update server/localtime realtime in PHP?

For school I am making a "virtual alarm clock" that needs to go off at a certain time. I get the time from a MySQL query and want to compare that with the actual time.

I've tried to update a variable realtime by putting it in a infinite while loop:

```
while(1) 
            {
                $hour = date('G');
                $minute = date('i');
            }
```

and to compare that with the output from a query

```
if ($hour == $hourquery && $minute == $minutequery)
        {
            do something
        }
```

but this way the page won't load.

I've searched something for Javascript as well, because it will update on client side too. But I couldn't find anything where I could store the time in PHP variables.

Comment: I think what you'd want to do is write it in Javascript, and then the Javascript will call a PHP script at the right time.  Or even better, depending on your self-imposed restrictions... make a cron tab.

Answer (score 2):

PHP should not work, because it is server based. You would have to reload the page often… which would end in your own Ddos.

Try javascript. Maybe [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) will help you on your further work. But an infinite loop for js doesn't sound bad.

Hope I could help

Comment: I don't have any experience with js. Convert the actual time to minutes and autorefresh the page every 60 seconds did the job.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: As said this method results in creating your own ddos, if more users use your site!

Answer (score 0):

you could try using alive connections such as websockets or ajax long-polling. For example, see Rachet for your case http://socketo.me/